# Does string interpolation evaluate duplicated usage?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

If I have a format string that utilizes the same place holder multiple times, like:

```
emailBody = $"Good morning {person.GetFullName()}, blah blah blah, {person.GetFullName()} would you like to play a game?";
```

does `person.GetFullName()` get evaluated twice, or is the compiler smart enough to know these are the same value, and should be evaluated once?

Comment: Surely it calls it twice. What if you're changing some global state in the method?

Comment: C# compiler is not able to detect [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) to my knowledge (which would be cool) and hence it can't "know these are the same value".

Comment: @StephenKennedy http://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/570292

Comment: Sorry, I am a python developer right now, and do not have access to an dev environment for C#. I was just curious

Comment: @NathanTregillus there are plenty online compilers like http://ideone.com/, but indeed online compiler with support c#-6 is hard to find.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: actually, detecting pure functions is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I expect compiler to perform practical version of detection (like "no external inputs/outputs and only standard constructs like `parm1*parm2`, other pure calls and `while(true){}` inside") which should be trivial (not an expert here, so would be glad to know where I'm wrong on this assumption). Splitting all functions into pure/non-pure (compared to pure/non-pure/unknown) indeed equivalent to Halting Problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The tricky part is that now you don't cover the cases perfectly; the function becomes rather brittle - adding a piece of code might still keep it being a pure function while the runtime will no longer treat it that way etc. Things like this are incredibly hard to debug.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, you surely don't need to cover every case, though. Many compilers will already detect the trivial cases of a program that won't halt. Similarly, we could also detect trivially pure functions (anything that doesn't use or modify a variable beyond function scope or call another function that is not considered pure). We could then build up a dependency tree of functions that are considered pure (so that we can determine what functions can be called without breaking purity). Of course, the case of `person.GetFullName` is probably not a pure function.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Yes, it will be evaluated twice. It can't know that it *is* the same value. For example:

```
Random rng = new Random();
Console.WriteLine($"{rng.Next(5)}, {rng.Next(5)}, {rng.Next(5)}");
```

It's exactly the same as if you just used the expression as a method argument - if you called:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", person.GetFullName(), person.GetFullName());
```

... you'd expect `GetFullName` to be called twice then, wouldn't you?

If you only want to evaluate it once, do so beforehand:

```
var name = person.GetFullName();
emailBody = $"Good morning {name}, blah blah blah, {name} would you like to play a game?";
```

Or just use a normal `string.Format` call:

```
emailBody = string.Format(
    "Good morning {0}, blah blah blah, {0} would you like to play a game?",
    person.GetFullName());
```

Comment: Can the compiler perform this optimization if it can prove that the function being called is a pure function?

Comment: @hexafraction Doesn't C# have an "as-if" rule? Any optimization should be allowed if it doesn't change the result.

Comment: @hexafraction, yes it could. It can get away with whatever it wants, as long as you can't observe the difference. Though note that in the general case, deciding if a function is pure amounts to the halting problem.

Comment: @Barmar: I'd still expect the more logical calls when debugging a debug build, of course. The side effect of "dev observed in debugger" is an interesting one :)

Comment: @PaulDraper You can prove that a function is pure, but you can't prove that a function is impure. E.g. any function that only calls other pure functions and operators is pure by induction. As long as there are no false positives, using this for an optimization is safe.

Comment: @JonSkeet You generally don't optimize when you're debugging.

Answer (score 12):

> is the compiler smart enough to know these are the same value [...]?

But it *won't* necessarily be the same value.  The method could very well return different results on subsequent invocations, so it *can't* cache the result.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the time, the compiler will be able to optimize this.  Unfortunately, the times it can't are also the times you would care most.

Optimization in this context is not based on calling the same function twice, but based on inlining.  Accessors usually are trivial (looking up a field, or at most doing a conversion between numeric types or format/parse between numeric and string type) and as such, easily meet the criteria for inlining.  Furthermore, the JIT prevents problems with cross-module inlining.  On the other hand, interfaces, delegates, and virtual calls can prevent inlining.

Once the compiler has replaced both calls by the function body, it sees two loads from the same field, and likely can use common subexpression optimization to actually fetch the field only once (as long as it can prove there is no intervening write from the same thread... in particular it doesn't have to worry about writes from other threads unless there's an intervening lock).

But this only saves an extra field fetch.  In cases where the accessor call is expensive (remote procedure call or database lookup), inlining won't be possible, and you're going to pay for two evaluations.  In such a case caching the result yourself is worthwhile.

Comment: "Most of the time" ... don't expect too much from the .NET JITs. RyuJIT, in my testing, loads field a twice in the expression a + a. I wouldn't believe it if I had not tested it myself.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a way for the compiler to be sure that a method will always return the same value. If you need such an optimisation, you have two options:

Use a variable:

```
string fullName = person.GetFullName();
emailBody = $"Good morning {fullName}, blah blah blah, {fullName} would you like to play a game?";
```

Using `String.Format`:

```
emailBody = String.Format("Good morning {0}, blah blah blah, " +
            "{0} would you like to play a game?", person.GetFullName();
```